# How to clone a gitlab repo when you are using github authentication?

Tags: git, github, oauth, gitlab

I used Github authentication for Gitlab. Now when I'm trying to clone a repo, it asks for a username and password, so I tried to use my Github username and password, but it returns an error.

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/groupname/front-end.git/'
```